# How to set current date and year in DatePickerDialog in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement datepicker dialog in Android but it is not showing current date. It's showing old calender when pops up and year is not same in calender and header also. I want to show current date in calender.

Below is screenshot of datepicker dialog that I am getting:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
public class BookDoctor extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

EditText date;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_doctor);

    date = findViewById(R.id.date);

    date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDatePicker();
        }
    });
}

private void showDatePicker(){

    final Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
    int dayOfMonth = cldr.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = cldr.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = cldr.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,this,dayOfMonth,month,year);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

   String dat = dayOfMonth + " - " + month+1 + " - " + year;
   date.setText(dat);
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the available constructors for **DatePickerDialog** [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog)

To sum it up - change the order of the arguments as follow:

`DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,this,year,month,dayOfMonth);`